# Double tap issue on button checkbox for iOS mobile iPhone

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sass, safari, touch

I found some issues on checkbox button on a Bigcommerce application when it is used on iOS on mobile/touch devices.

I have checkbox button with label and :hover effect and iPhone need double tap to check the button.
The first tap activate the :hover the second one check the box.

If I uncheck the button with single tap it remains the :hover effect on it.

I've tried several ways with javascript to avoid them: 
 - trigger click() on touchstart/touchend
 - trying to update CSS substituting :hover with :active
- onclick="void(0)" in html elements

My test in local environment are fully functional but in production environment I get the double tap issue.

the link to the page is here: https://links.ricompro.it/test-css-button-ios-safari
and it happens on the bottom part of the page where you can find the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem myself, and after intensive research I found that the problem is caused due to the use of Fastclick in the application. This problem may no longer be relevant to you, but in case others need a fix, this little CSS takes care of it:

```
label > * {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See this issue: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/60

Comment: not relevant for me in this moment, but useful for the future of everybody, thank you!